# JAVA: How to calculate the average of days through multiple dates which are strings?

Tags: java, string, date, average, difference

I wrote a program, which always calculates the difference of days between two dates.
I want to now some sum up all the days of the differences and divide it through the count so that I get the average day.
Can someone help me? Is there a way to even avoid the for-Loop.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class AVGDateCalculation {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws ParseException{
    String formatted =
            "2014-04-28 ,2014-04-28 ,"
            + "2015-10-26 ,2015-10-30 ,"
            + "2015-07-30 ,2015-07-30 ,"
            + "2015-04-14 ,2015-04-20 ,"
            + "2013-11-14 ,2013-11-18 ,"
            + "2014-04-16 ,2014-04-22 ,"
            + "2014-11-19 ,2014-11-21 ,"
            + "2019-10-01 ,2019-10-01 ";

                String[] parts = formatted.split(",");

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                int count = 0;
                int a;
                long difference = 0L;
                float daysBetween = 0.00f;
                float averageDays = 0.00f;
                Date dateBefore = null;
                Date dateAfter = null;
                for (a = 0; a<parts.length; a+=1) {
                    dateBefore = sdf.parse(parts[a++]);
                    count++;
                    dateAfter = sdf.parse(parts[a+=0]);
                    difference = dateAfter.getTime() - dateBefore.getTime();
                    daysBetween = (difference / (1000*60*60*24));    
                    averageDays = (count / daysBetween);

                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(dateAfter) + " - " + `String.valueOf(dateBefore));`
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(dateAfter.getTime()) + " - " + String.valueOf(dateBefore.getTime()));
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(daysBetween));
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(averageDays) + " days");
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(count));
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Quick bug spot: `averageDays = (count / daysBetween)` should be `averageDays = daysBetween / count`

Comment: `parts[a+=0]` `a+=0` does nothing

Comment: when you do `parts[a++]` you are incrementing  `a` meaning you are skipping things in the list

Comment: also to get an average you want to collects all the date differences  in the loop. then divide once at the end. as count keeps getting bigger the date range you add means less than the previous and they should all count the same.

Comment: @mavriksc the dates appear to come in pairs, which could explain the "skipping".

Comment: yes they come pair by pair and i let calculate the difference of each pair but unfortunately i cant get a sum date difference so i can divide that through count :(

Comment: Do you care about elapsed time in milliseconds? Or is your goal a count of whole calendar days?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment under my first answer and assuming you have always an even count of dates in your original string here is another approach.

Briefly summarized :

- split your input at every comma,
- calculate the difference of every second pair by iterating in the for
  loop in two steps `(i = i+2)`,
- save the differences in a list,
- calculate the average by adding the values in the list and dividing
  by the list size

Hope it is clear. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Test2{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {    
            String formatted =    "2014-04-28 ,2014-04-28 ,"
                                + "2015-10-26 ,2015-10-30 ,"
                                + "2015-07-30 ,2015-07-30 ,"
                                + "2015-04-14 ,2015-04-20 ,"
                                + "2013-11-14 ,2013-11-18 ,"
                                + "2014-04-16 ,2014-04-22 ,"
                                + "2014-11-19 ,2014-11-21 ,"
                                + "2019-10-01 ,2019-10-01 ";

            List<Long> diffs = getDifferences(formatted);
            System.out.println(diffs);
            double averageDiff = averge(diffs);
            System.out.println(averageDiff);
    }
    public static List<Long> getDifferences(String input) throws ParseException{
        List<Long> differences = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] dates = input.split(",");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        for(int i = 0; i<dates.length; i = i+2){
            differences.add(differenceBetween(sdf.parse(dates[i+1]),sdf.parse(dates[i])));
        }
        return differences;
    }
    public static long differenceBetween(Date date1, Date date2){
        long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
        long msDiff= date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
        long daysDiff = Math.round(msDiff / ((double)MILLIS_PER_DAY));
        return daysDiff;
    }
    public static double averge(List<Long> diffs){
        double sum = 0;
        for(Long d : diffs){
            sum += d;
        }
        return sum/diffs.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, you are a true genius.

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit                               // An enum delineating granularities of time.
.DAYS                                    // `DAYS` is one of the objects pre-defined on that enum.
.between(                                // Calculates elapsed time.
    LocalDate.parse( "2015-10-26" ) ,    // `LocalDate` represents a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone.
    LocalDate.parse( "2015-10-30" )      // `LocalDate` by default parses strings that comply with standard ISO 8601 formats.
)                                        // Returns a `long`, the number of days elapsed. Uses Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/42dKvM).

> 4

## Wrong class

The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC, not a date. Furthermore, that terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Your inputs comply with ISO 8601, so you can parse directly. No need to define a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2015-10-26" ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time using `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.of( start , stop ) ;
```

Or ask directly for number of days.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use `LocalDate` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`, because there you can calculate the difference and many other things more easily. To split your dates that appear in pairs you can use a regex that separates your string at every second comma.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.LongSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String formatted
                = "2014-04-28 ,2014-04-28 ,"
                + "2015-10-26 ,2015-10-30 ,"
                + "2015-07-30 ,2015-07-30 ,"
                + "2015-04-14 ,2015-04-20 ,"
                + "2013-11-14 ,2013-11-18 ,"
                + "2014-04-16 ,2014-04-22 ,"
                + "2014-11-19 ,2014-11-21 ,"
                + "2019-10-01 ,2019-10-01 ";
        //a formater for your date pattern
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //a function to calculate the date differnce for a given pair of dates of form "2014-04-28 ,2014-04-28"
        Function<String,Long> dateDiff = s ->  ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                        LocalDate.parse(s.split(",")[0].trim(), dtf), 
                        LocalDate.parse(s.split(",")[1].trim(), dtf));
        //split your original string at each second ',' with below regex
        LongSummaryStatistics statistics = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\G[\\d -]+),")
                .splitAsStream(formatted)
                .mapToLong(s -> dateDiff.apply(s))
                .summaryStatistics();  
        System.out.println(statistics);
    }
}
```

The statistic contains the sum, the count, the minimum, the maximum and the average. If you are only interested in the average, you can also call it up directly

```
    double average = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\G[\\d -]+),")
                .splitAsStream(formatted)
                .mapToLong(s -> dateDiff.apply(s))
                .average().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: That is a good solution, so I upvoted it. Unfortunaly the Environment I am working with uses the oldest of JAVA and this doesn't support everything, so I have to find a way to do it with the SimpleDateFormat. Is there any way to do it with that or is it just impossible?

Comment: The oldest of Java, is that Java 1.4 or older? As Basil Bourque explained in the other answer, java.time has been backported to Java 6 and 7. If on Java 5 consider [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead. It’s not impossible with `SimpleDateFormat`, but you should regard it as a last resort because that class is so troublesome.